# avoid vtable mixup in c++ variadic template inheritance

Tags: c++, polymorphism, variadic-templates, c++20

I have an idea to architecting classical entity-component in a better way with variadic template inheritance. This question stems from funky experiments in the context of 3d-graphics but i believe i have it broken down to a very abstract question about C++. I am able to use   C++20 in the scope in which it is currently implemented in Microsoft `cl` aka. the MSVC++19-Toolchain.

So. A few Base classes:

```cpp
class basic {
public:
  std::wstring get_name() { return name; }
  virtual void do_something_idk_virtual() = 0;
  virtual ~basic() {}
private:
  std::wstring name;
}
class has_legs {
public:
  virtual void walk() = 0;
  virtual ~has_legs() {}
}
class has_wings {
public:
  virtual void fly() = 0;
  virtual ~has_wings() {}
}
template<typename... Ts>
class entity : public basic, public Ts... {
public:
  virtual ~entity() {}
}
```

So far, so good. Now i want to make a duck:

```cpp
class duck : entity<has_wings, has_legs> {
public:
  virtual ~duck() {}
  virtual void walk() { cout << "walk" << endl; }
  virtual void fly() { cout << "fly" << endl; }
  virtual void do_something_idk_virtual() { } // nothing,
}
```

still, seems to work. The problem is: I know have  data structure (say a linked_list, or some sort of graph) and I use the visitor-pattern to work with `basic*`-typed things. I now have a lot of Code that looks like this. This is, quite literally, the central and critical part of a my program:

```
void visit(basic* node) {
  //here i find out, through magic or some other kind of out-of-scope-mechanism that node is at least a has_wings. Problem:

  reinterpret_cast<has_wings*>(node)->fly(); //does not work, will call basic::do_something_idk_virtual(). As far as i understand, this is because the compiler-generated vtable does not change via the reinterpret_cast.
  reinterpret_cast<entity<has_wings>*>(node)->fly(); //might, work, problems start to come in if node is of some type that has_wings and has_legs. It sometimes calls some other method, depending on the ordering in declaring the class.
}
```

#### Solution

1. Have every component (aka. the pure interfaces) and the `entity`-class virtually inherit from `basic`
2. in `basic` add the non-virtual method:

```
template<typename TComponent> TComponent* get_component() { 
return dynamic_cast<TComponent*>(this); 
}
```

This will then fix vtables. I am not sure why dynamic_cast does that.

Comment: You've mixed static and dynamic dispatch, and now have the disadvantages of both!

Comment: If you have a data structure of `basic*` then you should only do `basic` operations on those.  If you want to do `has_wings` operations, then you should have a data structure of `has_wings*` in addition.

Comment: This is what `dynamic_cast` does.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` won't even compile here as there is no possible valid conversion between `has_wings` and `basic`, though it might work with `basic` to `entity<has_wings>` - checking.

Comment: yea so it compiles but throws a runtime exception as `entity<has_wings>` is no superclass of `duck`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` to move within an inheritance hierarchy, and `static_cast` can’t descend virtual inheritance or cross-cast (in one step) because the layout of different classes that derive from the source and destination types may differ.  As it is, you’d have to know the **actual** type (not just that it had a given aspect) to do the conversion.  If you have your “aspect” classes **inherit** from `basic`—virtually, so that there is a unique `basic*` to be had—you can then use `dynamic_cast` not for its *checking* purpose but so as to find the appropriate vtable for the aspect in question.

If you can’t afford that, you may want to **amalgamate** the interfaces somehow.  You then have to be careful to call the functions only when they’re meaningful; that’s already the case (“through magic”), but then the ordinary call syntax might be an attractive nuisance.  You might also try some C-style polymorphism with a manually-created vtable with **function pointers** for each optional behavior.

Comment: Good answer, I will try the approach with having the interfaces virtually inherit from basic, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your template gives you nothing. `class duck : public basic, public has_wings, public has_legs` is absolutely identical.

Second, you need to decide what your level of polymorphic access is. If your level is `basic`, than it has to have already defined all the virtuals you want to be accessing (i.e. `has_wings`, `fly`) An interface where you need `dynamic_cast`s to arrive to correct dynamic type (your example with `reinterpret_cast` is just wrong, you can't use `reinterpret_cast` to move through class hierarchy) is a poorly written interface.

Sometimes visitor pattern can be employed, but in my mind, it tends to produce extremely hard to troubleshoot code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You are right that in my example the variadic template appears to be pointless; however it serves a very aesthetically pleasing purpose in the expanded version. This purpose has unfortunately been lost in trying to create a minimal representation of the problem. Am I right, then, that in your opinion there is no solution to my question as my problem is me being insane? (figuratively...)

Comment: >  it has to have already defined all the virtuals you want to be accessing

this seems to be the critical point. I thought there was a way around it. I'll wait a few hours and will then probably accept your answer.